# opening excel files

Tags: android, excel, spreadsheet

How can I open an excel from my android application and show it in table form. Is there any opensource library for that. if so please help me

Thanks and regards

pramod

Comment: One of the libraries in these answers would probably work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387201/java-library-to-display-excel-data

Answer (score 1):

Apache POI is your answer :) http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: can i display the file in table form just like excel and edit it.

Comment: this example will show you how to convert a spreadsheet to html  http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/html/ToHtml.java
and webview will help you in displaying it on an android device  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html